# Работа с кэш. Android

Tags: java, android

Вопрос, вроде как, банальный но, как записать обыкновенную строку в кэш, чтобы при повторном входе в приложение данные брались оттуда?

Есть такой код:

```
public static SharedPreferences readRules;
private String s;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    readRules = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

    if(readRules.getString("readRules", "").equals("true")){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainPageNavigation.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }else{
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Rules.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
```

Изначально в `readRulse` ничего нет, переходим в `MainPageNavigation`, там происходит запись при нажатии на кнопку:

```
btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
        ed.putString(readRules, "true");
        ed.commit();
        readRules = sPref.getString("readRules", "");
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainPageNavigation.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

При повторном открытии приложение не находит переменную `readRules`.

Comment: здесь кавычек не хватает вокруг readRules - `ed.putString(readRules, "true");` -> `ed.putString("readRules", "true");`

Comment: Это не помогло...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Метод `getPreferences(...)` возвращает `SharedPreferences` уровня активити.

Вы же хотите получить доступ к одним и тем же `SharedPreferences` из разных активити, для этого Вам нужно использовать `SharedPreferences` уровня приложения:

```
SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences (String name, int mode)
```

где `name` – название файла настроек, в обоих активити оно должно быть одинаковое.

Для ключей лучше использовать константы, а значение типа `boolean` лучше и сохранять как `putBoolean(...)`.

И да, как подсказывает в комментарии [@pavlofff](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/594374/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D1%8D%D1%88-android#comment800489_594374), Вы забыли кавычки в строке:

```
ed.putString(readRules, "true");
```

Вот по этой причине лучше и использовать в качестве ключей константы.